# Paragraph tag adds empty space between sections

Tags: html, css

When I begin or end a section of my HTML document with a `<p>` tag, it adds an "unclaimed" space between preceding/trailing sections.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
header {background-color: gray}
div.content {background-color: lightblue}
footer {background-color:gray}
</style>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width">
  <title>This is the title.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  This is the header.
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is paragraph #1</p>
    <p>This is paragraph #2</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    This is the footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image: Space outside tags]

Notice the space inserted above and below the `<body>` due to the `<p>` tags. There are a few things I can do to fix the formatting: I can remove the `<p>` tags and instead use `<br />` to style the text into paragraphs.

However, I ask this question because I would like to understand

1. Why doesn't the `<body>` section include the `<p>` spacing? What section does the `<p>` spacing "belong" to, if any?
2. Following the *intent* of the `<p>` tags, or HTML tagging in general, is there a "right" way to work around this behavior to both mark my paragraphs and get the format that I want (no white spaces between sections).

To be clear, I was expecting to see something like this:

[image]

... or this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of collapsing margins.

The top/bottom margins on the `p` tags collapse with the margins of `.content` (0 in this case) and then collapse with the margins of the `<header>` and `<footer>` (also 0).

Note that the `p` elements has a top and bottom margin by default (browser style sheet).

To get the effect that you expecting, you could trigger a block formatting context on `.content` by adding `overflow: auto` to the CSS rules for `.content`.

By so doing, the top/bottom margins of the `p` elements would be constrained within the edges of the `.content` block.

If `.content` had either a border or padding along the top/bottom edges, the paragraph margins would not collapse, because margins must be adjacent to each other in order to collapse.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wXv9t/

**Additional Explanation**

Background colors extend through the content, padding and border, but not the margin.  In this case, when the `p` margin collapses with the `.content` block, the top/bottom edges of the top/bottom `p` coincide with the top/bottom edge of `.content`, hence the background color of `.content` coincides with the top/bottom edges of the paragraphs.  With `overflow: auto`, the `p` margins are contained within the content box of `.content`, so the background color is seen through the margins of the `p`, so in this sense, the space is "reclaimed".

**References**

Collapsing Margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Block Formatting Context: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: To make sure I understand... It seems like there is an order of operations that is responsible for this effect. The positions of `header` `div.content` and `footer` are determined, then collapsing occurs on the paragraph margins. Without `overflow:auto`, the space will not be reclaimed by `div.content`.
Am I correct?

Comment: You are essentially correct, please see my extended explanation above.

Comment: Re-reading your explanation, it sounds like what I was expecting was the behavior of `padding`. Apparently the `margin` property is meant to put a neutral space between an element and its neighbors; the background color is not extended. If you want to add space that becomes "part" of the paragraph, you should adjust `padding` (or, as you suggest, put the paragraph in a container).

Answer (score 3):

The default margin spacing with many major browsers is `1em` before and after the `p` tag. Below is a screen capture within Chrome Developer Tools showing the default user agent stylesheet that is applied to all `p` tags, until it is overwritten.

[image]

Check out this fiddle that has no changes to the paragraph tag at all

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LgQh/)

Then compare it to this one below. Notice that I have added some CSS of `margin:0;` to remove the default margins that the user agent stylesheet applies.

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpdxz/)

```
p {
     margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for those spaces is that the browser has a user agent stylesheet that automatically adds margin to properly space paragraphs and certain other text elements.  You can just add

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to those

tags and it will override the user agent style sheet